# Sync move, copy and delete operations, not just files

Tags: linux, windows, sync

I was wondering if there is any synchronization method which doesn't copy files if they already are in the destination folder.

Let me explain:

I took some pictures and put them in a folder on my laptop. To back them up on my Ubuntu server I just ran `rsync -vrutP source des/ti/na/tion/`.
Then I decided to put all the RAWs in a sub-folder on my laptop (`source/RAW`) and the JPGs in another sub-folder (`source/JPG`).

Now, if I want to mirror this to the server I have to run `rsync -vrutP --delete source/ des/ti/na/tion/` but if I do so I get all my files deleted from the server and then copied again from my laptop to the server. I have several GBs of pictures and this is not a problem if have got time to wait and an Ethernet connection rather than a WiFi.

But wouldn't it be MUCH quicker, even if much more CPU demanding, if there were a command that compared the files in the root folder "source" and applied only the position differences between the source and the destination? More CPU would be involved to list all the files but I'd need almost no bandwidth to transfer files I don't really need to transfer because they're already in the destination, event if in a different place.
Of course a must-have functionality would be the delta synchronization, which would also detect if the existing (but moved) files are exactly the same as those in the source folder.

I have known about software doing this (Syncovery, Goodsync) but I actually wanted to know if there is any command doing this on Linux and on Windows.

Comment: I can't see how this could be done automatically, but performing the same move operations on the target system should stop any unnecessary copies: `rsync -n` will show you what operations will be done.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand yes... because you are on a very specific use case. On the other, moving or renaming files in Linux are the same thing. And to discover if a file on the source has just been renamed, the system would have to compare it (or its hash) to all the files in the backup, and therefore would have to read all the files in the backup to compute their hash... this would be very time consuming, unless the hashes are kept in a side database. There are storage systems that do so... but not your plain filesystems.